# Problemas para el manejo de columnas bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy realizando el diseño responsivo de un modulo de una pagina y cuando veo en pantalla pequeñas no logro que los bloques queden en filas, actualmente estan quedando en columnas estoy ocupando boostrap 3

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <br>
    <p class="precioCarritoCompra text-center">CLP $ <span>10000</span></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <br>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <center>
            <input type="number" class="form-control cantidadTipo" min="1">
            <input type="hidden" class="tipoProducto">
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <br>
    <p class="subTotal'+index+' subTotales">
        <strong>CLP $ <span>10000</span></strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

Resultado en pantalla menor a 767px:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que busco que los bloques del código queden ordenados en filas y no en columnas

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

En bootstrap 3 las clases de las columnas como *col-md-**, *col-sm-**, y *col-xs-** son combinadas por defecto, no es necesario especificar todas las clases para cada columna.

Cambia tu código por este cambio, se eliminaron *col-md-**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <br>
        <p class="precioCarritoCompra text-center">CLP $ <span>10000</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <br>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <center>
                <input type="number" class="form-control cantidadTipo" min="1">
                <input type="hidden" class="tipoProducto">
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <br>
        <p class="subTotal'+index+' subTotales">
            <strong>CLP $ <span>10000</span></strong>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**En las pantallas pequeñas (*col-xs-**), cada bloque ocupará el ancho completo de la pantalla, y en pantallas medianas (*col-sm-**), se dividirán en filas de 3 bloques.**

Con esto deberías poder ver los cambios.